# Why do I get a 403 error when attempting to access AWS S3 from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

I am wanting to access S3 from a Spring Boot application using Spring Cloud AWS.  My access to S3 works fine from my desktop, but when I bundle the app up as a WAR file and deploy to an EC2 Tomcat container, I get an 403 exception:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 4F0EBE3A853C6D99)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1078) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.27.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:726) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.27.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:461) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.27.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:296) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.27.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3737) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.27.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1028) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.27.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.io.s3.SimpleStorageResource.getObjectMetadata(SimpleStorageResource.java:182) ~[spring-cloud-aws-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.io.s3.SimpleStorageResource.exists(SimpleStorageResource.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-aws-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
```

I have an `application.yml` where I define access to AWS:

```
cloud:
    aws:
        region:
            static: eu-west-1
            auto: false
        credentials:
            accessKey: myaccesskey
            secretKey: somereallylongkeyhere
            instanceProfile: true
```

This works fine from my desktop.  What see do I need to do to make this work?  I have tried turning on every permission I can see within S3 but I can't seem to get around this.

Comment: It sounds like you have the AWS credentials configured, so it is most likely an issue with your EC2 instance's network configuration. Does your instance have a public IP address? Does your instance belong to a security group with restricted outbound rules?

Comment: Yes, it's got a public IP and full inbound/outbound access.  The 403 make me think its a credential issue - is there anything funny that happens to the resources files when they get packaged up into a WAR?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the culprit was an outdated system clock. EC2 instances can sometimes drift and IAM API is very sensitive to it. Relevant information can be found here: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2885.

Comment: share some info from that link plz. Else your post gets useless when the link gets removed